# Quantitative Aptitude Average

Tags: average

The average weight of a group of boys and girl is $38$ kg.

The average weight of boys is $42$ kg and that of girls is $33$ Kg.

If the number of boys is 25, then the number of girls is?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let there be $g$ girls.  What is the total number of children?  What is the total weight?  What is the total weight of boys?  What is the total weight of girls?  What is $g$?